# Javascript, toFixed one decimal except when it is 0

Tags: javascript

I need to fix a number with decimals to just 1 decimal, so I tried this:

```js
const convert = (numberWithDecimal) => numberWithDecimal
  .toFixed(1)
  .replace('.', ',')
  .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");

console.log(convert(123.123)); // "123,1" that's ok
console.log(convert(123.005)); // "123,0" that's NOT ok
```

Code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/sp0fLrhb/3/
But, when the decimals are rouned to 0 I don't want to use it, for instance:

In `123.005` I need to get `123`, not `123.0`

Any help?

Comment: .replace(/,0$/,' '')

Comment: So how hard is replacing `.0` with an empty string? ;)

Comment: Someone edited my question with wrong idea

Comment: consider number.toLocaleString for localized decimal and thousands separators

Answer (score 2):

I guess the obvious simple solution is to add `replace(',0','')` to the chain.

```js
const convert = (numberWithDecimal) => numberWithDecimal
  .toFixed(1)
  .replace('.', ',')
  .replace(',0', '')
  .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");

console.log(convert(123.123)); // "123,1" that's ok
console.log(convert(123.005)); // "123,1" that's ok
```

Answer (score 2):

The entire **purpose** of the `.toFixed` function is to ensure a *fixed* number of decimal places, such as when displaying currency (you'll frequently display $25.00 instead of $25)

If you don't want a fixed number of decimal points (e.g. you sometimes want 0 and sometimes want 1) then you don't want to use `.toFixed`. Instead, try using multiplication and rounding to get the result you want:

```js
const convert = (numberWithDecimal) => String(
        Math.round(numberWithDecimal * 10) / 10
    )
    .replace(".", ",");
console.log(convert(123.123));
console.log(convert(123.005));
```

### An interesting note on performance

I like to profile solutions whenever possible and it ***seemed*** at first glance like my solution would be faster (I'm just performing some integer arithmetic whereas you're performing multiple string functions). So I wrote the following:

```
var d0 = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { convert(123.123); }
console.log(new Date() - d0);
```

I then tested our two solutions. On my machine your solution actually ran about 15% ***faster*** than mine. I don't know why, but if you're interested in maximum performance then your solution of multiple `.replace()` chains actually ran quicker (in Firefox on Mac OS X)

### Note 2 on performance

If you choose to go with the `Math.round()` solution but want it to run a ***bit*** faster, there's a hack in JavaScript to round numbers really quickly:

```
Math.round(123.123); // 123
Math.round(123.987); // 124

(123.123 + 0.5)|0; // 123
(123.987 + 0.5)|0; // 124
```

Note that this hack actually fails with negative numbers. But so long as you're dealing with positive numbers, this method is faster than calling `Math.round()` (and gets performance about on par with your solution

It works because bitwise operators in JavaScript (`&`, `|`, `^`, `~`) only operate on ***integer*** values. If passed a non-integer, they will first truncate the value (chop off any decimal points). Since we want to round and not truncate, we add 0.5 before truncation.

Comment: Nice solution, can you explain a bit more on the intuition on the multiplication and the division and how you arrived to it

Comment: The `Math.round()` function will round to the nearest *integer*, not to the nearest decimal point. Multiplying by 10 shifts the decimal point one place to the right. Dividing by 10 shifts the decimal point one place to the left. So I shifted the decimal point, then rounded, then shifted the decimal point back