# Javascript, 1 decimal in float number only with decimals

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty confused with a previous question that I made here, so I decide to create a new one.

Currently I have this code for formatting some numbers:

```
const convert = (numberWithDecimal) => numberWithDecimal
  .toString()
  .replace('.', ',')
  .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")

console.log(convert(12)); // "12" that's ok
console.log(convert(1234)); // "1.234" that's ok
console.log(convert(1234567890)); // "1.234.567.890" that's ok

// and now decimals
console.log(convert(1.2)); // "1,2" that's ok
console.log(convert(1234.5)); // "1.234,5" that's ok
console.log(convert(12345678.9)); // "12.345.678,9" that's ok
```

But here I have the problems with

```
console.log(convert(123456789.01)); // it should be "123.456.789,0" but I got "123.456.789,01"
console.log(convert(1234567890.02)); // it should be "1.234.567.890,0" but I got "1234567890,02"
```

I'm testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/sp0fLrhb/13/

How can I get only 1 decimal, when the number already have decimal, but not have a `,0` with the number have no decimals? I tried with `toFixed(1)` and also with `String(Math.round(numberWithDecimal * 10) / 10)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `toFixed(numberWithDecimal%1?1:0)`

Comment: Same question as before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285256/javascript-tofixed-one-decimal-except-when-it-is-0/64285318

Comment: After you do all the conversions, simply replace `/,0$/` with an an empty string.

Comment: It's not that direct and it's not the same question, there's a new condition that the 2nd answer covers

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
const convert = (numberWithDecimal) => {
 let fixed = numberWithDecimal
    .toFixed(1)
    .replace(".", ",")
    .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
 if (Number.isInteger(numberWithDecimal)) {
        return fixed.slice(0, -2);
 }
 return fixed;
}
```

Comment: This fails the first 6 test cases (and the `toString()` call is redundant)

Comment: Fails the last 2 cases

Comment: @Guy Incognito No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing `,0` with nothing should work.

```js
const convert = (numberWithDecimal) => numberWithDecimal
  .toFixed(1)
  .replace('.', ',')
  .replace(",0","")
  .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")

console.log(convert(12)); // "12" that's ok
console.log(convert(1234)); // "1.234" that's ok
console.log(convert(1234567890)); // "1.234.567.890" that's ok

// and now decimals
console.log(convert(1.2)); // "1,2" that's ok
console.log(convert(1234.5)); // "1.234,5" that's ok
console.log(convert(12345678.9)); // "12.345.678,9" that's ok

// But here I have the problems with

console.log(convert(123456789.01)); // it should be "123.456.789,0" but I got "123.456.789,01"
console.log(convert(1234567890.02)); // it should be "1.234.567.890,0" but I got "1.234.567.890,02"
```

Comment: This is not correct, the last two console.log are not what it expected